# Sqlalchemy: Refer to current class name in query to avoid hard-coding

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

In python 3, you can use `__class__` to refer to the current class.

So whilst below works fine, I wonder if that's the right approach in SQLAlchemy to avoid constantly hardcoding the class name in queries:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)

    @staticmethod
    def get(session, name):
        return session.query(__class__).filter_by(name=name).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your queries in classmethods, and use `cls` instead of the class name:

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, session, name):
        return session.query(cls).filter(cls.name == name).first()
```

As you can see in the example code, this allows you to reference class attributes like columns too, which provides more flexibility than relying on `.filter_by`.

The same principle applies to 2.0-style queries:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, session, name):
        return session.execute(sa.select(cls)).where(cls.name == name)).first()
```

Comment: Hmm, I could certainly do this for my staticmethods but I've this use case for regular methods as well.  I actually expected sqlalchemy to have an "inbuild" way to do this, but looks like that's not the case.

Comment: Instances can call classmethods too.